# Hackerrank Wrong Answer

Tags: java

I was practicing my coding skills on hackerrank 30 days of code.While Solving Day 4 problem of classes and instances it showed wrong outcome.[enter image description here][1]

Expected Output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOgMw.jpg

My Output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee27n.jpg

If you notice, there's an extra line in my code and it only comes when last input is old.
Can anyone tell how to fix this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnPZZ.jpg

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Person {
    private int age;    
  
    public Person(int initialAge) {
        // Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
        this.age=initialAge;
          
    }

    public void amIOld() {
        // Write code determining if this person's age is old and print the correct statement:
            if(age<0)
        {  age=0;
            System.out.println("Age is not valid,setting age to 0");
            System.out.println("You are young.");
            }
         
         else if(age<13){
       System.out.println("You are young.");}
     
    else if(age>=13&&age<18){
        System.out.println("You are a teenager.");} 
 else
    {  System.out.println("You are old.");
        }
    
}

    public void yearPasses() {
        // Increment this person's age.
    age=age+1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            int age = sc.nextInt();
            Person p = new Person(age);
            p.amIOld();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                p.yearPasses();
            }
            p.amIOld();
            System.out.println();
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you always call `System.out.println();` you will always print an extra line after every loop iteration. If you don't want that for the last iteration you can just wrap that line in a condition that checks for your iteration variable. Something like `if ( i < (T-1))`

Comment: i can't make any changes in main function,please tell if there's anything else i could do

Comment: Please pasted inputs and outputs as text in your question. Also put in a short text about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Person {
    private int age;    
  
    public Person(int initialAge) {
        // Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
          if(initialAge<0){
              age = 0;
              System.out.println("Age is not valid, setting age to 0.");
          }else{
              age = initialAge;
          }
    }

    public void amIOld() {
        // Write code determining if this person's age is old and print the correct statement:
          if(age<13){
              System.out.print("You are young.");
              System.out.println("");
          }else if (age>=13 && age<18){
              System.out.print("You are a teenager.");
              System.out.println("");
          }else {
              System.out.print("You are old.");
              System.out.println("");
          }
    }

    public void yearPasses() {
        // Increment this person's age.
          age++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            int age = sc.nextInt();
            Person p = new Person(age);
            p.amIOld();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                p.yearPasses();
            }
            p.amIOld();
            System.out.println();
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working, output is still the same

Comment: @tanujabhatnagar I updated answer. This should be accepted answer by HackerRank

Answer (score 0):

this is my try:

```
public class Person {
private int age;    

public Person(int initialAge) {
    // Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
     if(initialAge>=0) age=initialAge;
     else{
      age=0;
      System.out.println("Age is not valid, setting age to 0.");
     }
}

public void amIOld() {

    if(age<13)System.out.println("You are young.");
    if(age>=13 && age<18)System.out.println("You are a teenager.");
    if(age>=18) System.out.println("You are old.");
}

public void yearPasses() {
    // Increment this person's age.
      age=age+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for HackerRank - 30 Days of Code - Day 4 classes and instances

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Person {
    private int age;    
  
    public Person(int initialAge) {
        // Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
          
          if (initialAge > 0) {
                age = initialAge;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Age is not valid, setting age to 0.");
                age = 0;
            }
    }

    public void amIOld() {
        // Write code determining if this person's age is old and print the correct statement:
        String output="";
        if (age < 13) {
            output="You are young.";
        }else if (age < 18) {
            output="You are a teenager.";
        }else {
            output="You are old.";
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public void yearPasses() {
        // Increment this person's age.
          age++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

*i have tried this and i have rectify this error by using the following code;*

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Person {
private int age;

```
public Person(int initialAge) {
    // Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
     if(initialAge<0)
    {
        this.age=0;
        System.out.print("Age is not valid, setting age to 0.");
    }
    else
        this.age=initialAge;
      
}

public void amIOld() {
    // Write code determining if this person's age is old and print the correct statement:
      System.out.println("");
        if(age>=0 && age < 13){
             System.out.print("You are young.");}
        else if(age>=13 && age < 18){
             System.out.print("You are a teenager.");}
        else{
            System.out.print("You are old.");}
        
}

public void yearPasses() {
    // Increment this person's age.
      age=age+1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        int age = sc.nextInt();
        Person p = new Person(age);
        p.amIOld();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            p.yearPasses();
        }
        p.amIOld();
        System.out.println();
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

}